# Will my Linksys AE2500 run on Ubuntu?

Tags: wireless

I have a Linksys AE2500 made by Cisco and was wondering if it will work or run with no "hiccups".

Comment: It's probably easiest just to try it. Use a liveCD or DVD.

Answer (score 4):

I tried it on my Sony desktop pvc-rs710 and it works but not stable.

What I tried with this wireless Linksys AE2500 on my Sony desktop Ubuntu:

1. From another computer with network connection, download ndiswrapper*.tar.gz and Windows XP driver for this wireless from Cisco site.
2. Copy both files (ndiswrapper tar and windows XP wireless zip file into /tmp)
3. Extract and install with these commands

   ```
   tar -xzvf ndiswrapper...
   cd ndiswrapper
   sudo make uninstall
   sudo make 
   sudo make install
   unzip Windows xp wireless driver zip -- we will have file *.inf in xp folder
   sudo ndiswrapper -i xp/<file>.inf
   sudo modprobe ndiswrapper
   ```

Comment: `sudo make uninstall` won't make a thing. You should scrap that.

Comment: Also, from this [article](http://www.grailbox.com/2012/05/installing-cisco-linksys-ae2500-wireless-adapter-in-linux/), you might want to add `sudo ndiswrapper -m` to `/etc/modules`-file.

Answer (score 3):

It will be challenging. Please see [this Ubuntu Forums thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1805830&highlight=AE2500).

And here: [Installing CISCO Linksys AE2500 Wireless Adapter in Linux](http://www.grailbox.com/2012/05/installing-cisco-linksys-ae2500-wireless-adapter-in-linux/)

I suspect it will work in a 32-bit system only.