# I cant get the internet to run (Linksys AE2500)

Tags: wireless

I have a wireless Linksys AE2500 network adapter to connect to the internet but when i boot Ubuntu there is no internet connection. What do i do now??

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/217312/will-my-linksys-ae2500-run-on-ubuntu-12 and http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2077873

Answer (score 0):

I didnt lokk at those links, but, if you still have problems, chack for pririty drivers (System Settings > Adittional Drivers. In 12.10 it's in the last len of "System sources")

also, chack the company site for linux drivers. If you need help with installing, just say (:

Well: http://support.linksys.com/en-mea/support/adapters/AE2500 I don't see a linux driver, but I know there's a project to make drivers for wireless. It has a site with the downloads and any download has a guide. If you don't fine it' I can search, or maybe the friends here will give you al link (: